# wp_mail() inside AJAX handler never returns

Tags: wp-mail

We have an AJAX handler called by jQuery.ajax() that takes a document stored on the server and mails it to the user. At the bottom there is a call to wp_mail like so:

```
$status_wpmail = wp_mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers, $filename);
```

Problem is the email never gets sent out, and any code *after* the wp_mail call never gets parsed, including a debug statement to dump out the value of $status_wpmail. The jqXHR response sent back to the page reports 'success' however.

I put in debug statements inside the handler to dump comments to a text file, and have confirmed statements are dumped to file right up to the wp_mail call. I've also enabled debugging statements per this [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) but I don't get any debug logs generated in wp-content.

Using a separate script to test wp_mail with a simple message and attachment I confirmed that wp_mail does work. I've also ruled out mail() as the culprit by installing the WP Mail SMTP plugin where this behaviour continues to persist.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** I've opted for a workaround by directly calling phpmailer and skipping wp_mail. The message successfully sent after doing that. Still would be nice if anyone knows why wp_mail would hang like that.

Comment: have you tried it without an attachment?

Comment: Yup I've tried it without an attachment and also hardcoding in values.

Comment: What exactly are you calling through your AJAX-Request? An PHP File or an WP Action?

Comment: Is your SMTP credentials set? Could you try setting them using these plugins and then use wp_mail(),
WP SMTP - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-smtp/
WP Mail SMTP - https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/

Answer (score 0):

You can do some simple debugging:

1. Try: `wp_mail('youremail@com', '123', '123');    // to see if it will go through`
2. If #1 is not, check if you setup SMTP correctly    `// install a smpt plugin(wp smtp mail/easy wp smtp)` and send a test email
3. If you can't send out a test email by plugin, check if your email account has correct rights to send out email from third party *(like
   yahoo mail requires "generate an app password", etc
   https://wpmailsmtp.com/docs/how-to-set-up-the-other-smtp-mailer-in-wp-mail-smtp/#secure-yahoo)*
4. If you use correct method to configure your email settings, but email still doesn't go out, check if your web server blocks the port 25,
   465 and 587 *(telnet the email server with these ports)*

My issue is `wp_mail` is blocking "Reply-To" option in `$headers` now, everything works fine from my AJAX request as long as "Reply-To" option is removed from `$headers`. Not sure if you have same issue.